# PHP Registration - don't allow duplicate rows

Tags: php

This my PHP code and I used `mobile_number` as primary key and I want to insert new users from an Android app where there's no duplicate users based on `mobile_number`.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blood");
$response = array()
if ( isset($_POST['frist_name'])&& isset($_POST['last_name'])&&isset($_POST['gendar']) &&isset($_POST['don_date'])&&isset($_POST['birth_date'])&& isset($_POST['blood'])&&isset($_POST['mobile_number']) && isset($_POST['pass'])  && isset($_POST['email'])) 
{   

$frist_name = $_POST['frist_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$gendar = $_POST['gendar'];
$don_date = $_POST['don_date'];  
$birth_date = $_POST['birth_date']; 
$blood=$_POST['blood'];
$mobile_number = $_POST['mobile_number'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$email = $_POST['email'];  



$result = mysqli_query($link,"Insert into login(frist_name,last_name,gendar,don_date,birth_date,blood,mobile_number,pass,email,latitude,longitutde,address) values('$frist_name','$last_name','$gendar','$don_date','$birth_date','$blood','$mobile_number','$pass','$email','0','0','not iserted')");

if ($result)
{

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Registration successfully.";    
     echo json_encode($response);

}
else
{
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
  echo json_encode($response);  
}
```

Comment: Just saying but there are **A LOT** of typos in your column names and data you insert.

Comment: We call him [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/),  On topic, what is your exact problem? If mobile number is primary, cou cannot have duplicate rows per mobile number if you have the exact same strict validation.

Comment: why don't you use mobile number as primary column

Comment: i  used primary key as primary  and datebase will prevent duplicate rows ,, how can i translate this respond into php and to user at android app??

Answer (score 0):

You can user PHP's [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) & [mysqli_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php) immediately after calling `mysql_query()` function. These functions include detail about error & error number by the latest operation with database. Saying in code:

```
if ($result)
{
  $response["success"] = 1;
  $response["message"] = "Registration successfully.";    
  $response["errno"] = mysqli_errno($link);
  $response["error"] = mysqli_error($link);
  echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
  $response["errno"] = mysqli_errno($link);
  $response["error"] = mysqli_error($link);
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

**JUST MAKE SURE not to run any operation against database between the mysqli_query() & the above section**

Then with error & errno in hand, you can make the users aware of the fact that someone has been registered using their mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

when db prevent user from registertion this mean user alredy registered :]

```
else
{
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = "an user alredy registered";//this is solution
  echo json_encode($response);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try alter your mobile number column in database with unique constraint. So that, when there's duplicate mobile number, the db won't allow you to insert the data and it returns error.

Below is the description about SQL unique constraint. Hope this helps.

[SQL UNIQUE Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)